# How to find the value of A and B

Tags: vector-spaces

The value of dot product and the cross product of two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$  are given as $\sqrt{3}$ and $ 2 \sqrt{3}$. I have to find out the value of A  and B.

I can easily find the angle between two vector,by using the equations($AB \cos \theta = \sqrt{3}$ $AB \sin \theta =2 \sqrt{3}$ ) but how to get the value of A and B?

Comment: Do you mean the *magnitude* of the cross product is given?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem might be a good place to start.

Comment: How? but how to eliminate the resultant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $A$ or $B$, I am meaning only magnitudes.

$AB \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{3}$, $AB \sin(\theta) = 2 \sqrt{3}$.

Square both and add, $(AB)^2 = 3+12 = 15$. Thus, $AB = 1/\sqrt{15}$. 
$\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$.

With the above information, you can only get $AB$ and cannot resolve further. Thus, best may be to choose any pair satisfying the answer - like $A=1$, $B = 1/\sqrt{15}$.